# how can i sort a list of categories in alphabetical order in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sorting

This is my index function in controller page of category , i want to arrange all categories in alphabetical order , right now my categories are sorted with id number , what code i have to add

this is code in controller page of category-

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $data = Data::orderBy('category_name')->get();
    return view('auth.category');
}
```

& that is code in model page of category-

```
class addcategory extends Model{
    use HasFactory;

    public static function insert($array){
        $data= DB::table('tbl_category')->insert($array);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly True, but he's already there right `$data = Data::orderBy('category_name')->get();`

Comment: Yes I would agree, which makes the question rather difficult to understand as it appears to be doing the right thing already

Comment: Maybe they were stored in alpha order and the OP is just not seeing any difference when they look at this new output as compared to when done without the Order By

Comment: Agree. Will rollback the my first comment to flag this. Thanks

Comment: but categories are not sorted by this code they are still stored based on their id number

Answer (score 0):

**Use Like :**

```
$data = Data::all()->sortBy('category_name');
```

Reference : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sortby